# How to use vue3-sfc-loader with scss

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sass, vue3-sfc-loader

does anyone know how i would use vue3-sfc-loader, which lets me use vue without build tools, while still being able to use scss styling?

The following example is taken from [here](https://michaelcurrin.github.io/code-cookbook/recipes/javascript/packages/vue/no-build-step.html):

**Index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
      <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "vue": "https://jspm.dev/vue/dist/vue.js"
        }
      }
      </script>
  </head>

  <body style=margin:0>
      <div id="container"></div>

      <script type="module">
      import Vue from 'vue';

      container.innerHTML = '<p>{{ message }}</p>';

      new Vue({
        el: '#container',
        data() {
          return {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
          }
        }
      });

      </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**myComponent.vue**

```
 <template>
    <span class="example">{{ msg }}</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          msg: 'world!',
          color: 'blue',
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <style scoped>
    .example {
      color: v-bind('color');
    }
  </style>
```

I want to use this for a small project. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

since vue3-sfc-loader v0.9.4, asynchronous style processor is available.
See the following sass example:
https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader/discussions/181